# sqlite: Do I need a index if I already have multi-column primary key?

Tags: sqlite

If I create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tiles 
(
     X INTEGER NOT NULL, 
     Y INTEGER NOT NULL, 
     Zoom INTEGER NOT NULL, 
     Type INTEGER NOT NULL, 
     Tile BLOB NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY(X, Y,Zoom,Type)
)
```

Do I still need to add a index on `(X, Y, Zoom, Type)` to make the searching fast?

My search query is like this:

```
SELECT Tile 
FROM Tiles 
WHERE X = %1 AND Y = %2 AND Zoom = %3 AND Type = %4
```

My insert query is like this:

```
REPLACE INTO Tiles(X, Y, Zoom, Type, Tile) 
VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: An index would not help the query planner any because the primary index (the PK is an index implicitly) is covered.

Comment: Use [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) to check whether a query uses indexes.

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite, when you declare a primary key an index is automatically created, see for instance the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html), so there is no need to create another index.